# Unable to instantiate activity componentinfo classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, android-activity, classnotfoundexception

I've developed an app but when I run it, it crashes and shows the error: android unable to instantiate activity componentinfo classnotfoundexception.

I've read a lot about this error. I've tried Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries and all other library projects are checked.

I've also noticed that when I press ctrl and pass the mouse over, for example, .MainActivity in my Android Manifest file, it doesn't display or link me to the Activity, don't know why.

Any ideas about this problem? Thank you so much.

---

**EDIT: Manifest added**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.isa.mememe"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </manifest>
```

Comment: Do you know what to do, don't you? :) Please post your code.

Comment: @valbertos Have a 1000 lines manifest, but I paste just the main part :)

Comment: You have a crash with activity **componentinfo** and here you paste only part of your manifest that does not include anything for this activity, and you consider that this is the main part, i.e enough information for us to help?